# Illegal string offset in php, among other php syntax errors

Tags: php

I've recently copy pasted code from a tutorial on paypal adaptive payments, found here:

http://proggblo.blogspot.ca/2013/04/paypal-adaptive-payments-parallel.html

However, I've run across some apparent syntax errors. Perhaps deprecated due to newer versions of PHP? (currently using 7.0.5)

The first issue is this piece of code:

```
  $sum;

  foreach ($itemsArr as $key=>$value) {

    $sum+=$value["price"];

  }
```

if I leave this as is, I get the error

```
Undefined variable: sum
```

Alright. So change that to

```
sum = 1;
```

hoping the original code wanted an integer and not a string. But then I get a new error:

```
Illegal string offset 'price'
```

which is coming from

```
$sum+=$value["price"];
```

I'm not entirely sure what to replace this with.

Next up is

```
$payKey = $response['payKey'];
```

which is giving me the error:

```
Undefined index: payKey
```

Help?

Comment: what is in `$itemsArr`?

Comment: you can look at the full code source linked in my post

Comment: I don't know if you are using the same `array`, can you paste the `addReceiver` calls

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/uYvmeTh6YaDsRBpb6rUhiB

Here is my entire file. I haven't really changed anything from the original so far.

Comment: The third parameter must be provided an array of arrays, try to test your code only using the first call to `addReceiver` on line 259.

Comment: Err, ignore my last paste.http://paste.ofcode.org/y43kZqDXkEvFhBmaqvy2tF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124841/discussion-between-felix-maxime-and-thomas).